# How to write multiple group by attributes combination in single select query (SQL server 2014) without using subqueries?

Tags: sql-server

My Requirement is like , need to return the below result set as single table
without using nested group by or sub queries

```
Select
Count(*) as SameCountryRowCount

From RollupTest

group by

Country

Select
Count(*) as SameNameRowCount

From RollupTest

group by

Name


Select
Count(*) as SameCountryNameRowCount

From RollupTest

group by

Country, Name
```

Comment: include sample data and expected output

Comment: why country is not included in the select statement in the first query? also the row numbers vary for each query.

Comment: You're looking for one query that gives you the count of each unique country, count of each unique Name, and count of each unique pairing of Country and Name. Is that correct?

Comment: How can you make it one result set, when the queries return a different number of columns?  Or at least they would if you included the group by columns in your select.  And if you don't do that, your results will really have no meaning.

Comment: How about SELECT count(DISTINCT Country), count(DISTINCT Name), count(DISTINCT concat(Country,'---',Name)) ...; (I'm not 100% sure about the third column syntax, but this should express the idea)

Answer (score 0):

This is done with `grouping sets`:

```
Create table t(name nvarchar(10), country nvarchar(10))

Insert into t values
('A', 'x'),
('A', 'x'),
('A', 'y'),
('B', 'x'),
('B', 'x'),
('C', 'z')

Select name, country, count(*) as c
from t
group by grouping sets((name, country),(name),(country))
```

Output:

```
name    country    c
A       x          2
B       x          2
(null)  x          4
A       y          1
(null)  y          1
C       z          1
(null)  z          1
A       (null)     3
B       (null)     2
C       (null)     1
```

Ot you can group by cube if you need total count:

```
Select name, country, count(*) as c
from t
group by cube(name, country)
```